# Wordpress Add Rewrite Rule

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am working on the domain [nygaardnotes.org](http://nygaardnotes.org). I would like to redirect all URLS that are `/issues/(name).html` to `/archive/issues/(name).html`.  I am using the following in `functions.php`

```
function rewrites() {
  flush_rewrite_rules();
  add_rewrite_rule('^issues/(.+)\.html$', '/archive/issues/$1','top');
}

add_action('init','rewrites');
```

I have tried some other variations/plugins/modifying htacces, but nothing has worked.  The current code above does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Did you visit the permalinks page to flush rewrite rules?

Comment: `add_rewrite_rule('^issues/(.+\.html)$', '/archive/issues/$1','top');` ?

Comment: Thanks Thomas, that fixed my problem.  I still don't understand why your change made the code functional.  When I tried my code in Redirection, I was getting an infinite loop (/archive/archive/archive....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a plugin to redirect the URLs then this is what you are looking for [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/).

It adds a 301 redirection and works like charm.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried Redirection and it was giving me some problems.  After your suggestion, I tried it with Thomas' code above and got the results I was looking for. thanks!